# regex preg_match loop through different terms

Tags: php, regex

I want to go through a string and match on different terms, but can't get it working. I want to match on {tab ...} en {media ...} and handle them differently.

If I only match on one, it works:

```
while ($do = preg_match("/{tab(.*?)}/", $description, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset)){
```

But when I add the media tag, it doesn't work anymore. This is what I use now:

```
while ($do = preg_match("(/{tab(.*?)}/|/{media(.*?)}/)", $description, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset)){
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the regex delimiters and the way parens are used. Try this:

```
"/{tab(.*?)}|{media(.*?)}/"
 ^                       ^
```

Notice that the delimiters remain where they were. You might even try something like this:

```
"/{(?:tab|media)(.*?)}/"
```

I'm not sure what you meant by `handle them differently`, but most of the time, that means that you should keep them in separate regexes.

Answer (score 1):

This is enough:

```
{tab(.*?)}|{media(.*?)}
```

No need for that additional slashes. also you should use `preg_match_all` if you have more consequences of them in your string.

```
preg_match_all("/{tab(.*?)}|{media(.*?)}/", $description, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset))
```